# select all the text in a iPad Pages document

Tags: ipad

is it possible to select **all** the text in a *Pages* document with a simple action?

If so, how?

if not, is there any trick to change the font in all of the paragraphs in a document?

Answer (score 1):

Touch your finger anywhere on the document and hold for a second. Then remove your finger and a pop-up menu should enable you to "Select all".

Comment: No holding needed if you touch on an empty spot of the page.